# Logon screen in elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno

Since the installation of Juno, the time that appears on the logon screen is in English format (AM/PM), while French is the language defined in the settings, and the time and date are displayed correctly everywhere else. Is there a setting to fix this, or maybe it's a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you install Juno, you choose your time zone in the installation wizard.  This seems to affect the system date/time/language settings.  So when I booted up, the system showed me a date in Arabic (based on my time zone) and after logging in the date time in the bar at the top would be US/English format.  In System Settings -> Language & Region, I had to "Unlock" additional permissions, then press "Set System Language".  This should change the login screen to French.  This is the same behavior from Loki and Freya as well.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that the answer by Micheal H works as described. I've installed Juno this morning on my work notebook and was annoyed by the wrong locale on the lock screen. Stumbled upon this answer but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote(?)

Comment: I've seen comments saying this works, but for me it doesn't. While it appeared language support was not fully installed, after fully installing, it displayed my format in Swiss (if i'm not mistaken), my system was previously in Brasil. So i set it back to Brasil and after unlocking 'Set System Language'. It still displays AM/PM where it should be 24h format.